# PHPstan: Cannot access property $work on array|EntityInterface|null

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x, phpstan

I am developing a web app, trying to keep PHPstan's suggestions in check.

I am having some difficulties with this method:

```
/**
 * AJAX: deletes a work file
 *
 * @return \Cake\Http\Response|false
 */
public function delete()
{
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('ajax');
    $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);

    $data = $this->request->getData();
    $data = is_array($data) ? $data : [$data];

    $workFile = $this->WorkFiles->find('all')
        ->where(['WorkFiles.id' => $data['id']])
        ->contain(['Works'])
        ->first();

    $res = [
        'status' => 'error',
        'message' => __('The file could not be deleted. Please, try again.'),
        'class' => 'alert-error',
    ];

    if ($workFile->work->anagraphic_id == $this->authAnagraphics['id']) { // error #1
        if ($this->WorkFiles->delete($workFile)) { // error #2
            $res = [
                'status' => 'success',
                'message' => __('File successfully deleted.'),
                'class' => 'alert-success',
            ];
        }
    }

    return $this->response->withStringBody((string)json_encode($res));
}
```

The code itself works, but I'm having two phpstan errors:

1. `[phpstan] Cannot access property $work on array|Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface|null.`
2. `[phpstan] Parameter #1 $entity of method Cake\ORM\Table::delete() expects Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface, array|Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface|null given.`

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `->first()` can return EntityInterface or array or null. phpstan doesn't know which one you have. `null->work` is not a valid construct, nor is `->delete(null)`, so it's warning you about that. At the very least, you should be checking for a null return value and issuing an error, or else use `->firstOrFail` so an exception is thrown. I'm not sure what circumstances lead to an array being returned here (`->hydrate(false)` maybe?), your best bet for that might just be to add a PHPDoc comment to clarify that what you have will, in fact, be an entity object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use inline annotation then here:

```
/** @var \App\Model\Entity\WorkFile|null $workFile */
$workFile = $this->WorkFiles->find('all')
    ->where(['WorkFiles.id' => $data['id']])
    ->contain(['Works'])
    ->first();
```

But the comments are right, you are blindly using a possible null value afterwards, as such your code is not written correctly.

Use this instead:

```
/** @var \App\Model\Entity\WorkFile $workFile */
$workFile = $this->WorkFiles->find('all')
    ->where(['WorkFiles.id' => $data['id']])
    ->contain(['Works'])
    ->firstOrFail();
```